# Binding to a seperate component react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a base component that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import MapContainer from '../containers/Map'
import ControlPanelContainer from '../containers/ControlPanel'
import Sidebar from 'react-sidebar'

const App = () => (
    <div className = "sidebar">
        <Sidebar sidebar = {<div className = "control-panel"><ControlPanelContainer /></div>}
                 docked = {true}
                 pullRight={false}
                 shadow = {false}>
            <div className = "map">
                <MapContainer/>
            </div>
        </Sidebar>
    </div>
)

export default App
```

`MapContainer` basically creates a `react-google-map` component with a bunch of clickable markers. On click, the key and location data of that marker are placed inside a list in the data store.

`ControlPanelContainer` basically has the job of displaying that list in textual format alongside the map.

When I click on the marker I can see that my list gets updated successfully with the appropriate data by looking in the react developer tools in my browser. But the changes don't get propagated to ControlPanelContainer view. This is because the function that updates the state in the `MapContainer` section of the code isn't bound to the instance of the `ControlPanelContainer`(I think) , i.e. `props.onMarkerClick`:

```
<Marker
    {...marker}
    onClick = {() => props.onMarkerClick(marker)}
/>
```

my question is how can a function inside one component be bound to a separate component? Most of the tutorials online seem to concerned with something that looks like:

```
this.component = this.component.bind(this)
```

i.e. binding a component to itself. My first intuition was to create the update functions in the same file as the App class and pass them down as props to ControlPanelContainer and MapContainer. However connect method doesn't seem to play well with props passed into it.

```
const MapContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Map)
```

I'm not sure if there's an elegant solution to this or if the current structure of my code suggests that I'm not thinking in a 'react' way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All actions should go through reducers. There is no direct action from component to component in redux.

So what you have to do is to fire an action when a marker is clicked, that will produce a new state from the corresponding reducer.
In turn the state update will make bound properties to be updated, so in `ControlPanelContainer` you should have a `markers` prop (or equivalent) plus something like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        markers: state.xxx.yyy;
    };
}
```

With `xxx` being the name of reducer for markers and `yyy` the object containing markers in the state.

Any update of `state.xxx` from Redux will trigger a `markers` prop change in your component.